# Firebase security and rules

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

Just a quickie, I'm trying to get my head around Firebase security protocols and I have set up a database called UsersDB which will store details based on auth.uid.  The details being full name, email, provider, account created date, last login date.

I have setup a rule as follows:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null", // only authed users can read/write
    ".write": "auth != null",
    "UsersDB": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth.uid == $uid", // users can read/write their own data
        ".write": "auth.uid == $uid"
      }
    }
  }
```

My understanding is that the record will only be able to be read and written by the person whose user_id matches the auth.uid.

My question is have I done this correctly and if not how should I have achieve this?  I only want the person creating the account to be able to read and write to this and no other uid to access the information.

Lastly, as a administrator of the firebase account.  I would be thinking of going down the line of creating a admin console type software which would allow me access to all the data stored.  How would I change or update the rules to allow an admin login to access the data above.  Would I change the read access to anyone (although this would seem to me to leave a vulnerability in the rules) or is there a way to declare a rule giving my (admin) full read access to all data?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're overlooking a very important part of the Firebase documentation that specifies that [permissions cascade](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/securing-data.html#section-cascade):

> SECURITY AND FIREBASE RULES WORK FROM THE TOP-DOWN
>
> The child rules can only grant additional privileges to what parent nodes have already declared. They cannot revoke a read or write privilege.

Since your top-level read and write rules already allow any authenticated users to read/write all accounts, you cannot revoke that privilege lower in the tree.

Luckily there is no need in your scenario to grant these higher-level permissions.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "UsersDB": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth.uid == $uid",
        ".write": "auth.uid == $uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With this each user can only read and write their own data.

Keep in mind that Firebase [rules are not filters](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/securing-data.html#section-filter). With the structure above, no user can query on `/UsersDB`, since nobody has read permission there.

Comment: Thanks Frank.  I understand what your saying about permissions cascade and what I originally setup.  I need to study it more and look for some examples to go through to get better understanding.

Comment: In the above rule each user is allowed only to read and write their own data, but say user_x is a super admin and I want user_x to read and write everyone data. Is that possible?